# How to inline edit table in angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

I need to inline edit a table i.e., to edit a table row in between. I have a table populated with data and each row has an button named Edit at the end. When I click on this button a dialog box opens with the contents of the particular row. I just want to edit those details and when a save button in dialog is clicked those details should be updated dynamically into the table.

Your timely help is very much appreciated.
I'm using angular material with angularjs.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same thing, be careful to use the correct tags. I've edited them for this question.

Comment: @JoeClay thank you it's been edited now

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to fill in some gaps here.
I'm assuming you are using some sort of modal to help you edit the row.

You can try creating a copy of the row's contents and passing that into the modal's scope, then when the user clicks save return the new contents and set the row. If the user hits cancel then we don't update that row

```
$scope.edit = function(index) { 
    $scope.editCopy = angular.copy($scope.rows[index]); 
    var modal = $uibModal.open({
        //... your modal here
    });

    modal.result.then(function(r) {
         if (r) {
             $scope.rows[index] = r;
         }
    });
}
```

Hope that helps.